# Minimize the time delay to copy,paste of complicated folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

My folder structure with **2000 folder** and **every folder having 2000 csv** file(every csv file size:upto 3KB).

But my problem is when i copy paste whole folder to other place it takes about 6 hours.
So i need to minimize that time using batch file.I want to **know why it takes like this much** and any **idea to solve this problem**.

```
data
|-----LrK90001
|         |----LrK90001.csv
|         |----LrK90001_e.csv
|         |----LrK90002.csv
|         |----LrK90002_e.csv
|                    .
|                    .
|                    .
|         |----LrK91000_e.csv
|
|-----LrK90002
|         |----LrK90001.csv
|         |----LrK90001_e.csv
|         |----LrK90002.csv
|         |----LrK90002_e.csv
|                    .
|                    .
|                    .
|         |----LrK91000_e.csv
    .
    .
    .
|-----LrK92000
|         |----LrK90001.csv
|         |----LrK90001_e.csv
|         |----LrK90002.csv
|         |----LrK90002_e.csv
|                    .
|                    .
|                    .
|         |----LrK91000_e.csv
|
```

### My pc spec:

Processor - Intel i5

RAM       - 16GB

Comment: The why is simple: four million files to check. Do you need to do everytime a full copy of all the files or only update an existing copy?

Comment: @MCND i need full copy of all files

Comment: 4 million files of max 3kB each makes 12GB max of files. Storing your files on a small, relatively inexpensive SSD (or better NVME) would probably make an enormous difference. It may also allow you to run a couple of parallel streams to do the copying - though you would need to experiment.

Comment: 2Gb/hour does seem slow. You are copying over a network, correct? If so, please describe your network connection and the purpose for the copy, e.g. backup, sharing, etc.

Comment: No i am not copy over network,just copy and paste local file

Comment: It would probably be faster to just clone the entire disk then. Are your drives SATA III?

Comment: @thx1138v2 you mean zip and copy paste zip file and unzip?

Comment: That would be for a network transfer. For a local drive it would probably be faster to just clone the entire drive.

Comment: @thx1138v2 my local folder size only around 6 Gb,but it takes about 6 hours,.i think the folder structure leads it to the issue.so i need any other way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146862/discussion-between-thx1138v2-and-selvarajmas).

Comment: That's 185 files/second that your system is managing to look up - which is pretty good. What do you expect?

Comment: @MarkSetchell i try another folder with same size but it contain 10 file it takes only 15 minutes to paste,